# How to output multiple lines using a single condition?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file with the pattern:

```
n0 n1 n2 ... ni
-------------------------------
N0 N1
<empty line>
```

if N0 is less than a specific number, I want:

- 2 lines above the N1's line
- N1's line
- Empty line below N1's line

to appear at the output. How can I do this using `awk` or any other utility?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Using "awk"

This will print lines with N0 < LIMIT:

```
# -v sets variables which can be used inside the awk script

awk -v LIMIT=10 '

    # We initialize two variables which hold the two previous lines
    # For readability purposes; not strictly necessary in this example
    BEGIN {
        line2 = line1 = ""
    }

    # Execute the following block if the current line contains
    # two fields (NF = number of fields) and the first field ($1)
    # is smaller than LIMIT

    ($1 < LIMIT) && (NF == 2) {
        # Print the previous lines saved in line2 and line1,
        # the current line ($0) and an empty line.
        # RS, awk's "record separator", is a newline by default

        print line2 RS line1 RS $0 RS
    } 

    # For all other lines, just keep track of previous line (line1),
    # and line before that (line2). line1 is saved to line2, and the
    # current line is saved to line1

    { line2 = line1; line1 = $0 }
' file
```

Comment: Doesn't work as expected. I realized that I needed `N0 < LIMIT` and hence changed `$2 > LIMIT` part to `$1 < LIMIT` but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: @Utku I just realized that I forgot to check for matching lines with 2 numbers only. I updated the answer; try this.

Comment: Yep it works now. Could you also explain step by step how this works? I'm new to awk and I would like to understand how it works :)

Comment: @Utku I added some comments to the code

Comment: Thanks. By the way, are `line2` and `line1` are not built in variables right? They are implicitly defined just before the last line?

Comment: @Utku I introduced these variables myself; they're not builtin ([list of built-in variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK#Built-in_variables)). If you want to define variables explicitly e.g. because you want to assign them a value, you'd do this in a BEGIN block which is executed before the input is processed. `BEGIN { a = 5; b = "hello" }` for example.